# using ig-json-parser with annotationProcessor from android studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio-3.0, jsonparser, annotation-processor, android-apt, android-gradle-3.0

In the new version of gradle, the 'android-apt'-pligin is no longer compatible.

now you have to user 'annotationProcessor' instatof 'apt'

so far so good.

I do the folowing:

Remove the class path for the apt from the build.gradle (Project: MyApplication)

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

Remove the plug in from the build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

Change the dependencies from apt to the new annotationProcessor

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.instagram.ig-json-parser:processor:master-SNAPSHOT'
```

gradle sync workes so far but the *__JsonHelper are not beeing generadet anymore!

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed and closed here:
https://github.com/Instagram/ig-json-parser/issues/47#issuecomment-342523796